# escape Hebrew double quote on both php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, escaping, hebrew

I'm working on multi-language site based on php.

For supporting multi-language, I'm using localizing file like below.

[localize.en-US.php]

```
$lang_code = "en-US";
$is_rtl = false;

.
.
.

define("WORD_EMAIL", "e-mail");
define("WORD_NAME", "name");

.
.
.
```

Defined words used by two way like below.

[HTML]

```
<?=WORD_EMAIL?> : <input type="text" name="email"/>
<?=WORD_NAME?> : <input type="text" name="name"/>
```

[Javascript]

```
if(frm.email.value==="") {
 alert("<?=WORD_EMAIL?> required.");
 return false;
}
```

The problem occured when I'd working on Hebrew.

The word "e-mail" of Hebrew tanslation has a double quote in it.

I tried to escaping double quote.

To escape double quote,

PHP need one backslash, and javascript need one more and one another for backslash.

**So I added 3 backslashes before double quote.**

it shows propery on javascript alert. but on HTML backslash(for javascript) appears..

Yes, I Know using single quote can solve this simply.

But it occurs an exception among localize files(some French word uses single quote).

Can anyone help about this? Any clues welcome.

Comment: shabbat shalom goyim maybe this will help you <BR><br>
http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you put all translations in an array. Then you can send that array correctly to javascript using `json_encode()`. You can try that out using `alert(<?= json_encode(WORD_EMAIL); ?> + " required.");`. And of course when outputting to html you need `htmlspecialchars()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always need to encode or escape values for the context you're embedding them in. When putting anything into HTML, you need to HTML-encode it unless you accidentally want the values interpreted as HTML. When putting anything into Javascript source code, you need to escape it properly there, for which JSON-encoding happens to be the right technique:

```
<?= htmlspecialchars(WORD_EMAIL, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); ?> : <input type="text" name="email"/>
```

```
alert(<?= json_encode(WORD_EMAIL); ?> + " required.");
```

Also see [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).

I would argue that your [i18n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) approach of pretty flawed though; "אִימֵיְיל required"* seems like a very insufficient localisation. You will want to look into proper tools like gettext and implementations/analogues of it for Javascript.

<sub>* Google translation, I don't speak Hebrew…</sub>